# No manual entries for basic commands like cp or mv

Tags: man, mandriva

I'm using OpenMandriva Lx 4.0 for a few weeks now and all in all it works very well on my small Netbook. 
Recently I've noticed that for some commands e.g. cp or mv there is no manual entry found on my system or it can't be found, but for other commands like netstat it will be displayed. 
I've checked that the packages man-db and man-pages are installed and also tried to reinstall them.

In another post there was suggested to try

```
mandb -c
```

which yields to the following output

```
updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man7'. Wait...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man5'. Wait...
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man5/regulatory.bin.5.gz: No such  file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man5/regulatory.db.5.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man9'. Wait...
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/:man9/skb_queue_head.9: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man9/__skb_queue_head.9.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/:man9/skb_queue_tail.9: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man9/__skb_queue_tail.9.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man1'. Wait...
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man1/openssl-rand.1ssl.xz is a dangling symlink
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man1/openssl-passwd.1ssl.xz is a dangling symlink
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man4'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man6'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man2'. Wait...
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man2/init_module.2: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man2/finit_module.2.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/mann'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man2x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man8x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man3'. Wait...
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man3/Class::Prototyped::why.3pm.xz: whatis parse for Class::Prototyped::why(3pm) failed
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man3/MIME::changes.3pm.xz: whatis parse for MIME::changes(3pm) failed
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man3/XML::Validator::Schema::SimpleType.3pm.xz: whatis parse for XML::Validator::Schema::SimpleType(3pm) failed
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man5x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man3p'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man8'. Wait...
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man8/setarch.8: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/uname26.8.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man8/setarch.8: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/x86_64.8.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man8/setarch.8: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/i386.8.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man8/setarch.8: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/linux32.8.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: can't open /usr/share/man/man8/setarch.8: No such file or directory
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/linux64.8.xz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/pcimodules.man.xz: ignoring bogus filename
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man8/saslauthd.8.xz: whatis parse for saslauthd(8) failed
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man4x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man1x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man3x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man1p'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man6x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man0p'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man7x'. Wait...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man9x'. Wait...
done.
Checking for stray cats under /usr/share/man...
Checking for stray cats under /var/cache/man...
...
```

However I'm not shure how to proceed in order to get the man pages configured properly. Does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: what is the result of `urpmi man-pages`? Have you tried updating your packages recently?

Comment: It kinda looks like the manuals have been manually (!) deleted.

Comment: `man-pages` are not installed at OS install time (Mandriva, Mageia, PCLinuxOS) .... Also : Plenty of on-line man pages https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv .... https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp .... http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html